# Databinding the StatusBar to another data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a status bar in the main app, which creates other user control on the fly. I want to expose the status bar so that the child user control can update the status bar. The data context of the main app is set to an instance of ConfigurationSettings. My attempt is this (not working):
In the Xaml:

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Name="StatusBar">
        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus">Ready</TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
```

And in the codebehind I have (inside the MainWindow class)

```
    // an inner class for data binding
    // ViewModelBase is an class that inherits INotifyPrppertyChanged
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string _Status = "";

        public string Status
        {
            get { return _Status; }
            set { _Status = value; OnPropertyChanged("Status"); }
        }
    }
    private MainViewModel _MainViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        configSettings = new ConfigurationSettings();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = configSettings;

        this._MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.StatusBar.DataContext = _MainViewModel;
        Binding statusBinding = new Binding("Status");
        statusBinding.Source = this._MainViewModel._Status;
        CurrentStatus.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, statusBinding);
    }
```

The ViewModelbase works because I use it in other view models.

The error message I got is:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Status' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=36924794)'. BindingExpression:Path=Status; DataItem='String' (HashCode=36924794); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='CurrentStatus'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to set the binding `Source` here as you have already set the `DataContext` so remove the line below and your binding will work:

```
statusBinding.Source = this._MainViewModel._Status;
```

Alternatively, as you have set the `DataContext` for your StatusBar, why dont you directly bind the TextBlock in xaml like

```
<TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus" Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Method 1 works beautifully. Thanks.
For the sake of learning, I tried the 2nd method. However, it didn't work. I tried both
`<TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus" Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>`
 and
`<TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus" Text="{Binding Path=Status}"></TextBlock>`

Comment: it should work.. have you removed the codebehind code where you are setting the binding? also can you check is it giving some errors in output window?

Comment: I commented out these two lines
`//Binding statusBinding = new Binding("Status");`
`//CurrentStatus.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, statusBinding);`

There was no error.

Comment: <TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Status, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType="{x:Type StatusBar }"}"}"> can you try thsi

Comment: Says XAML is not valid. The error starts at the = right after the first RelativeSource (indicated by a ~ right underneath that =)

Comment: my bad.. wrote code here only. quotes are not required <TextBlock Name="CurrentStatus" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Status, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StatusBar }}}">